# Delaying part of an R script inside of a loop

Tags: r, batch-file, foreach

I'm executing a batch file inside an R script. I'd like to run this and another large section of the R script twice using a foreach loop.

```
foreach (i=1:2, .combine = rbind)%do%{
    shell.exec("\\\\network\\path\\to\\batch\\script.ext")

    *rest of the R script*
}
```

One silly problem though is that this batch file generates data and that data is connected to SQL Server localdb inside the loop. I thought at first that the script would execute the batch file, wait for it to finish and then move on. However, (seems obvious in hindsight) the script instead executes the batch file, tries to grab data that hasn't been created yet (because the file isn't finished running) and the executes the batch file again before it finishes the first time.

I've been trying to find away to delay the rest of the script from executing until the batch script has finished executing but have not come up with anything yet. I'd appreciate any insights anyone has.

Comment: Have you looked at ?Sys.sleep()?

Comment: How is `shell.exe` defined?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`system2`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system2.html) instead of `shell.exe`. `system2` calls are blocking — meaning, the function waits until the external program has finished running. On most systems, this can be used directly to run scripts. On Windows, you may have to invoke `rundll32` to execute a script:

```
cmd = c('rundll32.exe', 'Shell32.dll,ShellExecute', 'NULL', 'open', scriptpath)
system2(paste(shQuote(cmd), collapse = ' '))
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but it sounds like that script is happening in the command window and not inside an R script.

Comment: Okay, I think the `cmd` threw me off. Its early here lol and I connected that to cmd window (stupid moment)

Comment: What is `shQuote(cmd)` and `collapse = ' '` doing? in the system2 function? I don't see them in the documentation.

Comment: @David You’re looking at the wrong documentation, they are unrelated to the `system2` call. I am nesting function calls here: you can call `f(g(x))`, which is the same as `temporary = g(x); f(temporary)`. To wit, I’m calling the functions `shQuote` and `paste` — those are the documentations you want to look at: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/shQuote.html · https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/paste.html

Answer (score 1):

Windows users may use `shell`, which by default has `wait=TRUE`, which will cause R to wait for its completion. You may choose whether or not to directly "intern" the result.

On unix-like systems, use `system`, which also defaults to `wait=TRUE`.

If your batch file simply launches another process and terminates, then it may need to be modified to either wait for completion or return a suitable process or file indicator that can be monitored.

Comment: What is the proper syntax for cmd in the shell function? Do I need to simply put whatever I would write in the command line to start a file? `"start path\to\batch\file.bat"`

Comment: For a `.bat` just the whole path (omit the `start`) should suffice. If you use `start` you'll need to specify the `/WAIT` switch there as well.

Comment: Does shell need to have the double \ as in other R functions? In other words `"\\\\server\\path\\to\file.bat"` instead of `"\\server\path\to\file.bat"`

Comment: also, I've been saying it wrong through the whole question but network not server path

Comment: Also when I do `shell("\\\\NETWORK\\Path\\to\the\\batch\\file.bat", wait = TRUE)` I get these 2 warning messages and then nothing happens. `running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c \\DOGBERT\ISO Projects\NHRC. Tasks\23. JMPT Development\Testing\IPR_AutoReg64.bat' had status 1` and `In shell("\\\\DOGBERT\\ISO Projects\\NHRC\004. Tasks\\23. JMPT Development\\Testing\\IPR_AutoReg64.bat",  :
  '\\DOGBERT\ISO Projects\NHRC. Tasks\23. JMPT Development\Testing\IPR_AutoReg64.bat' execution failed with error code 1`

Comment: Yes, or just reverse them to forward slashes, as Windows will accept either. `shell(shQuote("//server/path/to/file.bat","cmd"))`

Comment: @ A. Webb R is acting like its not going to let me put the path to a network.

`CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
The specified path is invalid.`